# Value count of columns in a pandas DataFrame where where string is 'nan'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the following `pd.DataFrame`

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_1': ['Elon', 'Jeff', 'Warren', 'Mark'],
    'col_2': ['nan', 'Bezos', 'Buffet', 'nan'],
    'col_3': ['nan', 'Amazon', 'Berkshire', 'Meta'],
})
```

which gets me

```
    col_1   col_2   col_3
0   Elon    nan     nan
1   Jeff    Bezos   Amazon
2   Warren  Buffet  Berkshire
3   Mark    nan     Meta
```

All column types are strings. I would like a way to obtain the number of rows per column where the cell value is `'nan'`.

Where I simply run the following I get always zeros as missing count since it doesnt check for string which contain nan.

```
>>> df.isna().sum()

col_1    0
col_2    0
col_3    0
dtype: int64
```

However, what I want is to get

```
col_1    0
col_2    2
col_3    1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: have you tried using `df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have `nan` as string , you can do :

```
df.eq("nan").sum()
```

output :

```
col_1    0
col_2    2
col_3    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I was just going to point out that OP is defining cells with the string `NaN` / `nan` rather than having actual NaNs in his dataset. In which the `eq()` would do a great job.

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot @eshirvana.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to see that you changed your initial code for the dataset. However, if you would like to extract all of the rows where you have the `'nan'` string, I would use a mask.

```
mask = np.column_stack([df[col].str.contains("nan", na = False) for col in df])
df_new = df.loc[mask.any(axis = 1)]
```

This creates a new data frame that you can experiment with.

Comment: yes true, sorry for that. I saw that I didn't choose the most explanatory dataset for the purpose. Yours is also very helpful and would give me the rows which are nan. Thanks! But I had to change the purpose of my question.